# (BackgroundWorker) i'm using while() trying to output numbers, but I have only number from last cycle outputing

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I need my program to output numbers from `0` to `n-1`, but it only outputs the last number in the cycle, so I have an empty label until `num` becomes `n-1`.

```
BackgroundWorker firstW;

public Win()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Initialize();

    panel.Controls.Add(CreateLabel(160, 160, "text"));

    Run();
}

void Initialize()
{
    firstW = new BackgroundWorker();
    firstW.DoWork += one;
    firstW.RunWorkerCompleted += two;
    firstW.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void two(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
    Int64 num = 0;

    while (num < 9999)
    {
        first.Controls[0].Text = num.ToString();
        num++;
    }
}

void one(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("In process");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're updating the label in `RunWorkerCompleted`, which is running on the UI thread. While the loop is executing, the UI thread will be blocked, and you won't see a value in the label until the loop is done running (which is why you only see the last value).

If you were going to make something like this work, you'd want to make use of the BackgroundWorker's progress reporting functionality. When your process is running in the `DoWork` event, you can periodically reach out to the UI via `ReportProgress`.

---

When you create the `BackgroundWorker`, enable progress reporting and tell it what to do:

```
firstW.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
firstW.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => first.Controls[0].Text = args.UserState.ToString();
```

Move your loop to the `DoWork` event, and in each iteration of your loop, call:

```
firstW.ReportProgress(0, num);
```